# How do I access a branch via a Podfile's source statement?

Tags: cocoapods

**Scenario:** I have a source which by default is the master branch of that source.   I want to be able to access a custom branch.

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

#use_modular_headers!

source 'https://gitw.RicSite.com/digital/mobile/ios/NativeApps/Fast/Ric-Cocoapods.git', :branch => 'AlamoFire/5.4.2'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

The 'source' doesn't allow for an extra parameter: 'branch'.

But I don't want to access the 'master' (default) until I merge.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Hey, I have run into the same issue. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pod 'YourPod', :git=> 'https://gitw.RicSite.com/digital/mobile/ios/NativeApps/Fast/Ric-Cocoapods.git', :branch=> 'AlamoFire/5.4.2'
```

for the pod you need. This is how I do this

Comment: I tried the syntax after the 'source' but CocoaPods got confused to my intent.

Comment: why do you need specifically source? I think you can achieve what you need without touching the source section

Comment: I was working with a communal source ('master').   I wanted to run a parallel branch for development before merging to the communal source.   I eventually dropped this project and shall focus on Swift Packaging instead.